# View is rendered before data is available in ngOninit

Tags: angular

I have a service that has the following method:

```
public GetContactPage() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3421/api/case?caseId=' + this.caseId + '&page=/contact';

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => {
            console.log(response.json()); //data is here
            response = response.json();
        });
}
```

My view is just

```
<div *ngIf="case">
<div [innerHtml]="case"></div>
</div>
```

Here is ngOnInit for my view:

```
  ngOnInit() {
      return this._caseService.GetContactPage().subscribe(data => {
      this.case = data; //data is undefined
    });
  }
```

In ngOnInit, the data is undefined.  I suspect that it is because the data has not returned from the server yet, therefore my view does not render.  Even when the data comes back, it still does not render.  I thought the view updates when the model changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .map(response => {
        console.log(response.json()); //data is here
        response = response.json();
    });
```

is missing a return

```
    .map(response => {
        console.log(response.json()); //data is here
        return response.json();
    });
```

without that `subscribe()` won't receive any data.

Comment: Ah, I feel so dumb...You rescued me again. For some reason, I thought the outer return was handling that...Sorry my javascript sucks.

Comment: :D, nothing to worry. `response => { ...}` is a function on its own right, and return only returns from this function.

Comment: Yes, i keep forgetting that resp => {..} is a callback, just shorthand syntax? So this function returns back to the outer one and the outer one then returns to ngOnInit...Correct?

Comment: Exactly . . . .. . .